# Json encode / decode issues

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have this function in PHP

```
json_encode(unserialize($response)));
```

and I obtain this

```
{&quot;photosets&quot;:{&quot;cancreate&quot;:1,&quot;page&quot;:1,&quot;pages&quot;:1,&quot;perpage&quot;:2,&quot;total&quot;:2,&quot;photoset&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;7212806405&quot;,&quot;primary&quot;:&quot;1099675&quot;,&quot;secret&quot;:&quot;bdef35451&quot;,&quot;server&quot;:&quot;7384&quot;,&quot;farm&quot;:8,&quot;photos&quot;:3,&quot;videos&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;_content&quot;:&quot;Seo&quot;},&quot;description&quot;:{&quot;_content&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;needs_interstitial&quot;:0,&quot;visibility_can_see_set&quot;:1,&quot;count_views&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;count_comments&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;can_comment&quot;:1,&quot;date_create&quot;:&quot;1385114442&quot;,&quot;date_update&quot;:&quot;13855&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;721593276&quot;,&quot;primary&quot;:&quot;10991539336&quot;,&quot;secret&quot;:&quot;a94a094acf&quot;,&quot;server&quot;:&quot;7335&quot;,&quot;farm&quot;:8,&quot;photos&quot;:2,&quot;videos&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;_content&quot;:&quot;Benzina&quot;},&quot;description&quot;:{&quot;_content&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;needs_interstitial&quot;:0,&quot;visibility_can_see_set&quot;:1,&quot;count_views&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;count_comments&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;can_comment&quot;:1,&quot;date_create&quot;:&quot;1385113740&quot;,&quot;date_update&quot;:&quot;1385141&quot;}]},&quot;stat&quot;:&quot;ok&quot;}
```

In a page I recall this javascript code

```
$(function () {
        'use strict';
        $.ajax({
            url         : location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/gallery_photolist.js',
            data        :   {
                                type : 'gallery'
                            },
            dataType    : 'json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            console.log('ok');
```

But it doesn't log nothing in console. In effect in Firebug i see that my page call correctly the javascript (i can see the encoded json in the tab) but I think that my script cannot parse correctly the Json (i have not the tab with title "JSON").

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: this is firebug window:

[image]

Comment: Are you calling a PHP script on the server side, um because you have a .js extension on that url parameter, to begin with. You would want to change that to .php to invoke the php process.

Comment: NO, no problem for that, in reality it is "fake", because it is routed from framework. And i can read that Json in Firebug, but not in "JSON" tab (maybe it can not interprete it)

Comment: Warning: Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize(). Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

Comment: Your "dataType" parameter should just be "json" per the docs

Comment: @ChinnuR no problem for that, no untrusted input here.

Comment: Try adding an error handler callback, inspect the parameters of the callback for any error messages. api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax Open developer tools and look for any error messages in the console. Look at the network tab of dev tools and look at the html req / resp. Look at the http status code of the response. Let us know what you find.

Comment: @jszobody changed with only json and nothing changed....

Comment: @ricksuggs added firebug printscreen. All ok but no JSON parsed, I think. missed "JSON" tab here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script is escaping the JSON before it's sending it along, hence why your Response tab shows escaped characters. That's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Try logging the result of `json_encode(unserialize($response)))` on the server side, immediately after the function call, to see if it is any different than what you get in the browser.. "how to debug"

Comment: OK, you are right ;) Used native framework function to (not) escape char. Thank you very much for indicate right way ;)